# How to log inside Kotlin's filter function?

Tags: android, filter, kotlin

Using Kotlin to filter a list

```
var datalist: List<DataType>
val list = datalist.filter {it.Id == currentFilterId}
```

would like to put in some log to debug the data

```
val list = datalist.filter {
                Log.d(TAG, "$it,  currentFilterId: $currentFilterId)
                it.postId == currentPostFilterId
            }
```

how to put in multiple lines of statements inside the filter function?

Comment: Does that (with closing quote) not work?

Comment: Where's the problem? This should work

Comment: oh my bad, the missing closing quote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried that? That will work properly.

```
val list = datalist.filter {
     Log.d("tag", " ... ")
     it.postId == currentPostFilterId
}
```

Comment: because 
     Log.d("tag", " ... ")
     it.postId == currentPostFilterId
is a statement/expression ?